# Python class inheritance not doing what I think it should

Tags: python, python-2.7

I think I understand class inheritance in python, basically you can inherit the attributes of the parent class on the child class for re-usability and also to "add" to it to make even more complex classes.

Here is my question: I have a `Car` class below that has `(model, color, mpg)` as parameters, after that I created a new child class called `ElectricCar` that inherits from the parent `Car` class...and now when I call `ElectricCar` with "`(battery_type, model, color, mpg)`, I get the following error:

> TypeError: init() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)

I know got to fix it. I need to add `self.model`, `self.color` and `self.mpg` to the `ElectricCar` class. But why do i have to do that? It seems this defeats the purpose of inheritance if I need to re-define again on the child class.

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self,battery_type):
        self.battery_type = battery_type

my_car = ElectricCar("molten salt", "Honda","black", "33")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to add `self.model`, `self.color` and `self.mpg` to the `ElectricCar` class.

You don't. Python allows you to call methods of parent classes you've replaced. You just have to call the constructor of the parent class explicitly.

The first argument of `ElectricCar.__init__` is the battery type. Store the rest of positional arguments in a list (`args`) and unpack them to the parent constructor:

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, *args):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(*args) # super().__init__(*args) in Py3k+
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

Comment: Thanks. It super() something people use a lot? Seems a bit cumbersome to me, might be easier to just re-initialize them again at least in simple code like this. Maybe in more complex expression it might be worth it.

Comment: @noob2014: yeah, `super()` is simple and solves a lot of problems. It's not limited to constructors. I suggest that you read [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super). Less flexible alternative to `super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(*args)` is `ElectricCar.__init__(self, *args)`.

Comment: @noob2014: `super()` is something people use a lot, but you could also do `ElectricCar.__init__(self, *args)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the `__init__` method, you are overriding the`__init__` method of the parent class.  Such overriding is why the [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) function was created.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass  model, color, mpg in your ElectricCar class. Then you can call super to initialize the base class.

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg
        print model
        print color
        print  mpg

my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)
print

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self,battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        self.battery_type = battery_type
        print battery_type
        super(ElectricCar,self).__init__( model, color, mpg)

my_car = ElectricCar("molten salt", "Honda","black", "33")
```